# How to correctly configure auto-removing of objects?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a bucket BUCKET. This bucket contains several folders. A folder has name FOLDER. I use it to store files, that have expire_date.

It seems I need to configure something else to activate auto-remove, because all files still exist, but their expire_date < current_date.

I tried to create a Lifecycle rule, but no result. I set prefix for the rule as "FOLDER/*", set checkbox "Clean up expired object delete markers" and "Clean up incomplete multipart uploads".

Comment: What do you mean by `expire_date`? Is this something of your own creation, or can you explain where this is configured?

Comment: It is possible to set an expire_date when you upload file to S3:
https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager#UploadInput
// The date and time at which the object is no longer cacheable.
    Expires *time.Time `location:"header" locationName:"Expires" type:"timestamp" timestampFormat:"rfc822"`

Comment: *Cacheable* means [Specifying How Long Objects Stay in a CloudFront Edge Cache (Expiration)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html). It does not related to deleting the objects from Amazon S3. For that, you would use an [Object Lifecycle Management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) rule with "Delete objects" configured (*not* delete markers or incomplete uploads).